# java cannot refer to non-final variable

Tags: java, class, gwt

The following code continues to give me:

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable textBoxPassword inside an inner class defined in a different method  Login.java  /ChurchWebLogin/src/com/gwt/churchweb/churchweblogin/client line 61

```
package com.gwt.churchweb.churchweblogin.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasHorizontalAlignment;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.CheckBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;

public class Login extends Composite {

    public Login() {

        VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        initWidget(verticalPanel);
        verticalPanel.setSize("329px", "186px");

        Label lblNewLabel = new Label("Sign into your account");
        lblNewLabel.setStyleName("gwt-Login-SigninLabel");
        verticalPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

        FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
        verticalPanel.add(flexTable);
        flexTable.setWidth("308px");

        Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label("Username:");
        lblNewLabel_1.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
        flexTable.setWidget(0, 0, lblNewLabel_1);
        lblNewLabel_1.setWidth("72px");

        TextBox textboxUsername = new TextBox();
        textboxUsername.setStyleName("gwt-LoginTextBox");
        flexTable.setWidget(0, 1, textboxUsername);
        textboxUsername.setWidth("204px");

        Label lblNewLabel_2 = new Label("Password:");
        lblNewLabel_2.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
        flexTable.setWidget(1, 0, lblNewLabel_2);
        lblNewLabel_2.setWidth("66px");

        TextBox textBoxPassword = new TextBox();
        textBoxPassword.setStyleName("gwt-LoginTextBox");
        flexTable.setWidget(1, 1, textBoxPassword);
        textBoxPassword.setWidth("204px");
        flexTable.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(0, 0, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
        flexTable.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(1, 0, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);

        CheckBox chckbxRememberMeOn = new CheckBox("Remember me on this computer");
        chckbxRememberMeOn.setStyleName("gwt-Checkbox-Login");
        flexTable.setWidget(2, 1, chckbxRememberMeOn);

        Button btnSignIn = new Button("Sign In");
        btnSignIn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                if (textboxUsername.getText().length() == 0
                        || textBoxPassword.getText().length() == 0) {
                        Window.alert("Username or password is empty."); 
                    }
            }
        });

        btnSignIn.setStyleName("gwt-Login-SigninButton");
        flexTable.setWidget(3, 1, btnSignIn);



    }


}
```

Comment: In addition to the link, the 'accept' is a way of thanking those that help you.  Clicking the up-arrow next to the posting is another way.  This assumes the comment is useful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
final TextBox textboxUsername = new TextBox();
```

and

```
final TextBox textBoxPassword = new TextBox();
```

should fix it.

Java requires references to variables from inner classes to be `final` variables (for reasons of concurrency management, I suppose).

Comment: I always though it was related to how anonymous classes are compiled and executed in the JVM, like if the execution of the anonymous function cannot be sure of the actual value of the variable because it's not retrieved dynamically during the execution but in a previous step, but it was just a guess..

Comment: It's not just anonymous classes; it's any inner classes.

Comment: It's perfectly legal to access non final fields from an inner class, otherwise 90% of my code wouldn't compile ;) The problem appears when the class is anonymous and hence declared inside a method..

Comment: ack! you're right, idk why I was thinking it was inner classes in general.

Comment: @JasonS Strange enough, I didn't see such error with JDK1.8. But when I compile with JDK1.7, this error shows up. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 4):

Local variables must be declared `final` if they are used in inner classes. You should write:

```
final TextBox textBoxPassword = new TextBox();
```

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous class instances should be able to access the surrounding scope’s local 
variables and parameters. However, an instance might outlive the method in which it 
was conceived (as a result of storing the instance’s reference in a field), and try to 
access local variables and parameters that no longer exist after the method returns.

Because Java cannot allow this illegal access, which would most likely crash the virtual 
machine, it lets an anonymous class instance only access local variables and 
parameters that are declared final. Upon encountering a final local variable/parameter 
name in an anonymous class instance, the compiler does one of two things:

- If the variable’s type is primitive (int or double, for example), the 
  compiler replaces its name with the variable’s read-only value.
- If the variable’s type is reference (String, for example), the compiler 
  introduces, into the classfile, a synthetic variable (a manufactured 
  variable) and code that stores the local variable’s/parameter’s 
  reference in the synthetic variable.